# How do I pass a compare function to the sort method instead of the key-function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, sorting

I know already that i can pass my own sorting criteria to the sort function by defining a function, which assigns keys to the objects that i want to sort. For example if i would like to sort a list of strings based on their length i could do:

```
def length(x : str):
   return len(x)

list = ["one","two","three"]
list.sort(key = length)
```

But could I instead just define a function such as:

```
def compare(x : str, y : str):
   return len(x) < len(y)
```

and pass that function as argument to the sort method, so that the list is sorted based on this compare-function?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Comparator functions can be turned into key functions, the standard library provides this with `functools.cmp_to_key`

Comment: What's your use case? It's rare that a comparison function is better than a key function.